# javascript not running. Firebug says "reload the page to get source for: ..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, bookmarklet

I am trying to develop a bookmarklet which add some javascript elements to head of webpage. But I noticed that one of them is not loading.
[image]

Is there is some way to overcome this problem. Is it possible to reload page without loosing appended scripts?

Comment: Knowing the design intention would be useful. You could theoretically cobble something together with localStorage or web sessions, but in general client-side changes are lost on reload and as far as I know there is no simple API to get around that. Bookmarklets are meant to be additive: use them on-demand on a page to add functionality to the page. Reload the page and you will need to re-run the bookmarklet. If your bookmarklet needs to load additional scripts, you may want to do it in a way other than appending to head.

Comment: That can have many reasons. Do you have any extentions installed? Is the certificate valid? Do you enter your page via the http or https protocol?  What does the network tab say? Just too many possible reasons for that issue to answer te question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sorry for such a silly question!! 
Actually its not about localStorage or something like that. 
It is a browser security issue. Here the javascript file which is showing this message is actually on HTTP not HTTPS. But webpage is using HTTPS. So when I try to load that file, browser prevent it from loading.

Simple solution is to give this javascript source a HTTPS URL like put it on Google drive and make file public then copy its GoogleDrive host URL.

Answer (score 0):

The question you asked like reloading the page after you add an asset in the header by javascript is not possible.

But there is a practise called `dynamic asset loading` in javascript. In this practise we will load the assets(js/css/anything) required dynamically, which means after the page is loaded and maybe depending on a user action. This is a very important technique in improving your website performance as your are not loading all the assets initially and load only when required.

You can read a example here : http://blogs.mpr.org/developer/2014/01/dynamically-loading-assets-with-pjax-and-require-js/